# Click method is not working for me when i am trying to automate web browser using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

while I was trying to automate the web browser, I used click method at the end to click the button, I gave button Id to find element but its opening the new automated browser but not clicking on "Start Download" button. I am getting no errors.  My code is given below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/progressbar/download.html")
time.sleep(20)
my_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "downloadButton")
my_element.click()
```

I tried click method to call the download button but its not working properly.

Comment: what error are you talking about, can you show? The code works when i try it, the button gets clicked.

Answer (score 0):

reason for this issue could be that the download button may not be ready to be clicked when the click() method is being called. you can try using the WebDriverWait class to wait for the button to become clickable before clicking it.

```
my_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "downloadButton")))

my_element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/progressbar/download.html")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#downloadButton"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/progressbar/download.html")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='downloadButton']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```